# Django Rest Auth with Facebook login?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I have seen a lot of answers online but never got any clarity about how to move forward.

I have configured `django-allauth` and `django-rest-auth` as per the documentation and have also added `appId` and the `accessKey` from facebook as per the documentation.

I don't understand what this error is all about?

```
"non_field_errors": [
        "Incorrect input. access_token or code is required."
    ]
```

It works fine with the normal login. But what configuration am i missing to make it login via JWT tokens?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and reading docs, i found that the access token is given by the Facebook API when initiating the login or sign up. That access token is passed to this API to get the JWT Token. I used the basic javascript snippet for this purpose check the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/accesstokens).